# Need way to approve bash cmd exec before running w/o affecting echo return

Tags: bash

Currently trying to write bash that will do the following.

- check if curl is installed
- print out "which curl" before running it so that the user is able to opt in/out of running something they consider unsafe.

Use case is when you download a big script from github and you want to have more control over what it is doing. Also to be more aware of how it works.

I am not sure how to include this opt in/out code without messing up the "return" echo.  Maybe the answer is to use something different that the read -n 1 -s -r -p code.  I like that solution because it allows hitting any key to continue.

To be clear.  If I check for YES/NO later on, it is messed up because it will contain the character used to continue by pressing any key.   In my output example the space bar was hit to continue

```
#! /bin/bash

# Returns YES if installed otherwise return NO
check_curl_installed() {
echo >&2 "Before running, the command will be printed below."
echo >&2 "Press any key to approve running it"
read -n 1 -s -r -p "which curl"
  echo ""
  if which curl > /dev/null; then
    echo "YES"
  else
    echo "NO"
  fi
}
main() {
  RESULT=$(check_curl_installed)
  echo $RESULT
  echo x${RESULT}x

}

main "$@"
exit 0
```

This is the output

```
user@computer:tmp$ ./check_curl_installed.sh 
Before running, the command it will be printed below.
Press any key to approve running it
which curlYES
x YESx
```

Comment: I don't follow. What is the user opting out of exactly? You say you want to give the user control over whether a script downloaded from github is executed, but your script is all about checking if curl is installed. I don't see the connection between the two.

Comment: Imagine you get a bash script.  If you want to safely run it or you want other people to safely run it by approving each exec you would modify it to ask for permission for each exec in the script.

Comment: The intent is to modify scripts in a way so that it isn't doing shady stuff on your computer.  It is a manual process.  I go through the script and find lines where it is running a command.  Above that command I add code to print what the command will do and allow the user to press any key to continue.   The problem is that bash doesn't allow us to simply "return YES"  as far as I know it has to be done using echo.  This creates a problem because the "press any key to continue" will be part of the output messing up the YES string.

Comment: My users know me, so there is trust that my efforts to help them more safely run a script will not result in printing A but running B to trick them.

Comment: You could use the [Bash debugger](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/), which allows you to step through any script command by command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the output of the function, use its exit status.

```
check_curl_installed() {
    echo >&2 "Before running, the command will be printed below."
    echo >&2 "Press any key to approve running it"
    read -n 1 -s -r -p "which curl"
    echo ""
    if which curl > /dev/null; then
        return 0
    else
        return 1
    fi
}

if check_curl_installed
then
    # do something
else
    # do something else
fi
```

Comment: Use the Jobs link to find people willing to do work for you.

Answer (score 0):

how about this modified version to get only the Y key to answer...

```
#! /bin/bash

# Returns YES if installed otherwise return NO
check_curl_installed() {
echo >&2 "Before running, the command will be printed below."
echo >&2 "Press Y key to approve running it"
read -n 1 -r -s -p "Which curl?"
  if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
    if which curl > /dev/null ; then
      printf "\nYES It is installed\n"
    else
      printf "\nNO It is not installed\n"
    fi
  else
    printf "\nExiting - not checking\n"
  fi

}
main() {
check_curl_installed

}

main "$@"
exit 0
```

Your echo result is, i think just pulling the first line of the check_curl_installed function...
Maybe if result was set to an array?

my testing around has shown that it's forgetting variables in the function at the higher main function. I even tried exporting to get the main function to work, but to no avail. I'm not super strong in bash, so i apologize on that.

Also might work better to put the echos inside each function, instead of shoving them into a variable...

Most, if not all, languages, only return one value from a function. Maybe this is why your output don't do as you want? a quick search brought this up https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408543/how-can-a-bash-function-return-multiple-values